# How do I change the value type of a particular key in a dictionary in a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
list = [
   {'rank': '1', 'name': 'Gus’s World Famous Fried Chicken', 'stars': '4.0', 'numrevs': '549', 'price': '$$'}, 
   {'rank': '2', 'name': 'South City Kitchen - Midtown', 'stars': '4.5', 'numrevs': '1777', 'price': '$$'}
]
```

I need to update `numrevs` to `int`.

I have this so far, but I can't get it to work:

```
list = [dt.update({k : int(v)}) for dt in rankings for k['numrevs'], v in dt.items()]
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically you can do it quite easy with that:

```
for d in mylist:
    d["numrevs"] = int(d["numrevs"])
```

As a remark: Don't name any variable `list`. `list` is a built-in function and to overwrite this function can only lead to problems therefore I renamed the list to `mylist`.

Answer (score 3):

For each dict in your list, create a new dict, where the value for each key is the same as the current dict, except for the values that you want to replace with an int.

Here I am calling the current list `list1` to avoid the confusion between the variable name and the built-in type name.

```
list2 = [ {k:(int(v) if k=='numrevs' else v) 
          for k,v in d.items()}
            for d in list1 ]
```